# PHP "re-require" files after ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

In my index.php file, I firstly require some files and make connection to the database with php..

```
<?php

// Require every .php file inside "phpClasses" folder
foreach (glob("phpScripts/*.php") as $filename) {
require $filename;
}

// Create the $db object
$db = Database::obtain(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE); 

// Connect to the database
$db->connect();

// Instantiate the "language" and "databaseQuery" classes
$lang = new language();     
$dbQuery = new databaseQuery();     

// Detect if the laguage has changed from the user and apply the new "current language"
if(isset($_GET["change_lang"])) {
    $change_lang = $_GET["change_lang"];
    $cur_lang = $change_lang;
} else {
    $cur_lang = $lang->getCurLang();
}
?>
```

In the same file, I include 'home.php' file to display database content..

```
<div id="cur_content" class="temp_content" data-tempPos="0">
        <?php 
            include 'pages/home.php'; 
        ?>
    </div>  <!-- #cur_content -->
```

In the 'home.php' file I re-create $dbQuery class and call getText() function like this:

```
<?php

$dbQuery = new databaseQuery();         

?>

<div id="content_home" class="cur_content_inner"> 

  <?php
$text_pos = 'home_inner_1';
    $dbQuery->getText($text_pos, $cur_lang);
  ?>

</div>
```

'index.php' remains without refreshing and user navigates via ajax calls. New content is loaded inside #cur_content div, deleting the previous one.

All works justs fine at the first loading of the page, but when 'home.php' is requested again (without index.php refreshing), I get php error because the initial 'require' is not happening.

How can I require these files again, after the ajax call?

Sorry, but I am new to this! ;)
Appreciate every help!

Problem solved -> http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/59450/

I used this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=="XMLHttpRequest") {
    foreach (glob("phpScripts/*.php") as $filename) {
        require_once $filename;
    }

    // Create the $db object
    $db = Database::obtain(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE); 

    // Connect to the database
    $db->connect();
}
```

Comment: each ajax request is completely independent of the original request that fetched the page. there's no need to "re-require" if everything was set up correctly to begin with.

Comment: I am not sure if I am correct, but I think that the 'require' works only for the first time because it's inside 'index.php'. After the ajax call, the new content is loaded inside a page's div, but 'index.php' does not refresh to require these files for the new db query

Comment: no. require works as many times you need. it's `require_once` that only works once. `require` is basically `include` with an added condition that execution aborts if the file can't be loaded for whatever reason. That being said, if the file being included/required does one-time things, like defining a function, then subsequent include/requires can/will fail.

Comment: I am assuming that when user navigates, a new page say "page.php" is called. How does home.php get requested again?

Comment: Every page is requested via ajax call and it's content is placed inside a div in 'index.php' page. 'home.php' is requested just like the other pages. 'index.php' is not refreshed to get 'home.php'.

Comment: Aah, got it. I will post the solution as an answer. It is easier (and proper) to post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will need to do is something like this:

Take this snippet and put it in a separate file, say `includes.php`

```
// Require every .php file inside "phpClasses" folder
foreach (glob("phpScripts/*.php") as $filename) {
  require $filename;
}
```

Now remove it from index.php and just add `includes.php` into all your navigational pages including `home.php`

Comment: The fact is that 'index.php' itself needs this snippet to function.

Comment: Then add it to index.php as well :-) Also, it will not matter, but you can change `require` to `require_once` so that there is no overlaps at any point - slight performance degradation, but better stability.